# Cypress failed to start on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: ubuntu, cypress

On a newly installed Ubuntu 19.04 distro, Cypress fails to start with the following error

> error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What dependencies do I need to install?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Dependencies), you should run:

```sh
sudo apt-get install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2
```

Comment: Current version of the Cypress dependency list, valid on Ubuntu v22: `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb`